# I want to remove json format

Tags: php, arrays

I have a json format like :

```
[{"Date range":"this-week","Frequency":"daily"}]
```

Now I want to show like

```
Date range : This week | Frequency : daily
```

from ajax response, how can I do it ?

Comment: you tagged question as PHP and array and asked that how you can do it in ajax? It's confusing

Comment: You want to do string manipulation? Anyhow, parse the JSON and then use the resulting data structure to assemble the information in any way you like. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You should try to avoid spaces in json keys. Here's some basic code that will work:

```
$yourJson = '[{"Date range":"this-week","Frequency":"daily"}]';
```

As object:

```
$jsonAsObject = json_decode($yourJson, false)[0];
$stringFromObject =
    'Date range'
    . ' : '
    . $jsonAsObject->{'Date range'}
    . ' | Frequency : '
    . $jsonAsObject->{'Frequency'};
```

As array:

```
$jsonAsArray = json_decode($yourJson, true)[0];
$stringFromArray =
    'Date range'
    . ' : '
    . $jsonAsArray['Date range']
    . ' | Frequency : '
    . $jsonAsArray['Frequency'];
```

And if the values are dynamic, there's no real way to change "this-week" into "This week". You'd have to map 1-1 all known values into what you want them to change to, eg

```
if ($value === 'this-week') {
    return 'This week';
}
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

I have kept `response` in the string because JSON always comes in string in response of AJAX

```js
const response = '[{"Date range":"this-week","Frequency":"daily"}]';
const parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response);//parse it to JS array/object
const allKeys = Object.keys(parsedResponse[0])//get all keys in array
const allValues = Object.values(parsedResponse[0])//get all values in array
const dom = `<div>${allKeys[0]}:${allValues[0]=="this-week"?"This Week":allValues[0]}|${allKeys[1]}:${allValues[1]}</div>`;
document.getElementById("append_here").innerHTML = dom;
```

```html
<div id="append_here"></div>
```